# Array comparison with Linq in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using linq in Asp.NET MVC project for database operations. I want to attract customers who have sitecode in the AgentHealth table. How can I do this with linq in one operation?

```
var CurrentCustomers = new List<Customer>();
var CurrentCustomersDisc = Database.Session
                                   .Query<agenthealts>()
                                   .ToList()
                                   .Select(x => x.sitecode)
                                   .Distinct()
                                   .ToList();

foreach(var CurrentDisc in CurrentCustomersDisc)
{
    var TempCustomer = Database.Session
                               .Query<Customer>()
                               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.deleted_at == null 
                                                 && x.SiteCode == CurrentDisc);
    if(TempCustomer != null)
    {
        CurrentCustomers.Add(TempCustomer);
    }               
}
```

Comment: Do you want to fetch one random customer from each agenthealth, `SiteCode == CurrentDisc` and place all these customers in a list?

Comment: Yes, CurrentCustomersDisc is an array of sitecodes and each customer has a sitecode.

Comment: Please check my answer. Furthermore, please update your question stating explicitly that you are looking for is a list that would contains a customer from each agenthealth, in order to be clear what is the questionable. Thanks

Comment: This looks like it could be done in a single simple query in SQL. I don't know about that linq-frontend-to-sql though. Is this Entity Framework?

Comment: @İsmail Kasap - Please tag the framework used - seems like NHibernate by the `Session.Query`, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select customers where their Id (or what the primary key is) in `CurrentCustomersDisc':

```
var CurrentCustomers = Database.Session.Query<Customer>.Where(c=>
     CurrentCustomersDisc.Select(cc=> cc.Id).Contains(c.Id));
```

Comment: Rica ederim ;) İsmail bey